# arithmetic operation on regex group javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, concatenation, grouping

Fairly straight forward question: Is there a way to perform arithmetic operation on a matched group in regex in JS.

Ex: I have string:

```
<img style="top:200">
```

I want to replace 200 or whatever number by dividing by 5, which would be 40 in this case. So output:

```
<img style="top:40">
```

I tried:

```
var d= c.replace(/top:([-]?\d*[\.]?\d*)/,'int:'+parseInt($1/5)+'px')
```

But I get

```
<img style="top:NaNpx">
```

Comment: Why would you use regex to parse HTML and CSS ?

Comment: In this case, it's a well-defined text that shouldn't present too many issues. It's not like he's trying to parse a whole HTML syntax tree.

Comment: use a callback with replace method `var c = '<img style="top:40">';

    var d = c.replace(/top:([-]?\d*[\.]?\d*)/, function(m, m1) {
      return 'top:' + m1 / 5 + 'px';
    });` ..... but it's a bad idea to use regex for parsing html

Comment: @PranavCBalan: awesome...thank you!! please post it as ans and I'll accept

Comment: True, anyway [parsing properly](https://jsfiddle.net/1owq9x2f/1/) and [replacing](https://jsfiddle.net/1owq9x2f/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a callback function with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)  method.

```js
var c = '<img style="top:40">';

var d = c.replace(/top:([-]?\d*[\.]?\d*)/, function(m, m1) {
  return 'top:' + m1 / 5 + 'px';
});

console.log(d);
```

---

**FYI** : But it's a bad idea to use regex to parse HTML.

---

Another method with [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) where applying  the replace method only for the style attribute value instead of applying to the entire string.

```js
var c = '<img style="top:200">';

var parser = new DOMParser();

var img = parser.parseFromString(c, "text/html")
  .querySelector('img');

img.setAttribute('style', img.getAttribute('style').replace(/\btop:([-]?\d*(\.\d+)?)/, function(m, m1) {
  return 'top:' + m1 / 5 + 'px';
}))


console.log(img.outerHTML)
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 5 seconds :P